# TensorFlow LinearRegressor contrib.learn predict does not match manually training predict results

Tags: tensorflow

I'm completely new to tensorflow and was just going through the GetStarted page + tutorials here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started

With the tf.contrib.learn example, I changed y slightly but still kept a straight perfect fitting line for simplicity.  However when I ask the estimator to predict, I'm not getting my expected result + the predict result I get when I don't use tf.contrib.learn and I was hoping someone can explain the difference.

**tf.contrib.learn**

With tf.contrib.learn I get predict result = [  9.84994888  11.78239346  13.71483707] and I was expecting it to be far more close to 10, 12, 14

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

features = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("x", dimension=1)]
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features)

x = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y = np.array([2., 4., 6., 8.])
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x":x}, y, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000)

estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)

print(estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn))

print(np.asarray([i for i in estimator.predict(x={'x': np.array([5., 6., 7.])})]))
```

**Training manually based on TensorFlow Get Started page**

Training manually, my predict result = [  10.  12.  14.] and is naturally what I expect.

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()

W = tf.Variable([2.], tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([0.], tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model_y_result = W * x + b

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
squared_deltas = tf.square(linear_model_y_result - y)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas)
print(sess.run(loss, {x:[1.,2.,3.,4.], y:[2.,4.,6.,8.]}))

y_ = tf.multiply(x, W)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

x_train = [1.,2.,3.,4.]
y_train = [2.,4.,6.,8.]

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(1000):
  sess.run(train, {x:x_train, y:y_train})

pred_y = sess.run(y_, {x:[5.,6.,7.]})

print(pred_y)
```

Would appreciate if someone can explain to me the difference and why / or what I'm missing and need to add in order to get tf.contrib.learn to have predict results that fit perfectly (as I think they should for this simple example).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you call `tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor` without specifying the optimizer you want, it will use an Ftrl optimizer (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/LinearRegressor). If you want to use the gradient descent optimizer, you can use

`tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features, optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01))`,

which should predict something like [  9.98047733  11.97054482  13.9606123 ]. While this is still not as good as with manual training, it proves already far better to use the same optimizer. The example with `contrib.learn` still gives some warnings (at least on my machine), so maybe the results will be the same if you manage to get rid of these warnings.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realise I can add an optimizer there so that's good to know.  But yeah, doesn't exactly do what I thought it should be doing.  On the tensorflow page, they use y=0,-1,-2,-3 and the linear relationship + predict off of it is perfectly linear.  I don't see why y=2,4.6,8 should change this.  Thanks

Comment: Could be due to the initialisation of the weights (which you probably can't control using Estimator)